# Clone a div exclude last child element

Tags: jquery, clone

I want to clone a whole `div` but exclude the last `<p>` element in that `div`. How to use jQuery to do that?

Original div:

```
<div class="clone">
    <p>Content<p>
    <p>Content<p>
    <p>Content<p>
    <p class="exclude">Content<p>
</div>
```

I want this after clone:

```
<div class="clone">
    <p>Content<p>
    <p>Content<p>
    <p>Content<p>
    <p class="exclude">Content<p>
</div>
<div class="clone">
    <p>Content<p>
    <p>Content<p>
    <p>Content<p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

clone the element then remove the last child

```
var clone = $('.clone').clone().find('.exclude').remove().end()
```

or

```
var clone = $('.clone').clone().children(':last').remove().end()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/grQ45/)

Answer (score 1):

Clone the elements you need and append them to a div:

```
var $clone = $('<div class="clone"></div>').append(
    $('.clone').children(':not(.exclude)').clone()
).insertAfter('.clone:first');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RqZyu/1/)